# ffmpeg, video Conversion

Tags: video, ffmpeg, file-conversion

I have 2 video.
Metadata files:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 2000.00 (2000/1) -> 30.00 (30/1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '89.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2012-10-23 08:10:51
  Duration: 00:00:08.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2017 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 640x480, 2006 kb/s, 28.53 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-23 08:10:51
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 48 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-23 08:10:51
At least one output file must be specified.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 90000.00 (180000/2)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '56_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : 3gp4
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 1946-11-02 07:14:31
  Duration: 00:00:05.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 239 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: amrnb, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, flt, 5 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1946-11-02 07:14:31
    Stream #0.1(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 480x320, 240 kb/s, PAR 65536:65536 DAR 3:2, 17.63 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1946-11-02 07:14:31
At least one output file must be specified.
```

They do not play on my website.
How to bring them to a form?

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 47.95 (5994/125) -> 23.98 (24000/1001)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'oceans-clip.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2010-05-18 04:24:00
  Duration: 00:00:46.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3342 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 640x264 [PAR 132:133 DAR 320:133], 3195 kb/s, PAR 127:128 DAR 635:264, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-05-18 04:24:00
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 144 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-05-18 04:24:01
At least one output file must be specified
```

I get the video to android and vinfone devices, and must play it on your site, but the player does not want to play. Metadata files that I get see the beginnings. The latter belongs to the metadata file that correctly reproduced on the site.

Comment: Voting to close because it's not very clear what your question is here… Possibly you could clarify what you mean by mean by "bring them to a form"?

Comment: sounds like you're interested in some kind of conversion of video files. However maybe instead of bunch of technical you could provide some human understandable explanation for what you expect :)

Comment: I made ​​changes to the description of